# Redirect 301 using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect from page
http://masterkanz.com.ua/index.php?route=product/category&path=79_103
to
http://masterkanz.com.ua/pishushchie-prinadlezhnosti/ruchki-sharikovye

Rule like

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/category&path=79_103 http://masterkanz.com.ua/pishushchie-prinadlezhnosti/ruchki-sharikovye
```

doesnt works. I read that problem can be in symbol "?". But what should I do?

Comment: The problem is that you are using a wrong directive to match against query strings. check @Nikhil "s  answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/category&path=79_103$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ http://masterkanz.com.ua/pishushchie-prinadlezhnosti/ruchki-sharikovye? [R=301,L]
```

I've tried this and it is working, you need to use {QUERY_STRING} to get the rule working.

I hope this helps.

Comment: a question mark is important at the end of the target url as it removes the orignal query strings from destination url